# Is it possible to send a function to another function with the same return type but different parameters?

Tags: c#

I have an AttachmentService.cs class that is currently used to upload images to a database and/or a cloud storage container. When uploading to the cloud I have some retry logic in place that I would like to reuse when being called by two separate methods. I would like to pass in each function as a parameter and then call them from within the method they have been passed into. Here are the two signatures I have currently:

C#

```
//Example: I want to be able to pass the first function and also the second
//I'm sure it can done with generics but can't seem to get it currently
private AttachmentUploadResult UploadAttachmentToGLS(Func<string, Guid, byte?[], string, AttachmentUploadResult> uploadFunction)
private AttachmentUploadResult UploadAttachmentToGLS(Func<AttachmentEntity, AttachmentUploadResult> uploadFunction)
```

I would like the above code to only have one signature that could take either

`Func<string, Guid, byte?[], string, AttachmentUploadResult> uploadFunction` or `Func<AttachmentEntity, AttachmentUploadResult> uploadFunction` so that my method could look like something like this:

```
private AttachmentUploadResult UploadAttachmentToGLS(Func<parameters, AttachmentUploadResult>uploadFunction)
{
    //Some retry logic
    uploadFunction(parameters);
    //Some more retry logic
}
```

Is there a way in which I can acheive the above? I have read into Func and do not believe this is the correct delegate to use.

Comment: The approach with two method overloads is the right one, in my opinion. The two methods have each a different argument parameter (different delegate types) that will have to be treated differently, obviously. Look around in the classes provided by the framework libraries, you will notice that providing/declaring method overloads is a common approach. No need trying to be too clever with your method declarations... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of your function can be just `Func<AttachmentUploadResult>` - you don't really care about the parameters in the `UploadAttachment` method, so you should close over them. The call might then look something like this:

```
Upload(() => SomeUploadMethod(theActual, parameters, toTheMethod));
```

It also allows you to hide the details of the implementation from the `UploadAttachment` method - all you care about is "this is the function to call when I want to do the upload".

Comment: Parameters are known only inside the method, so you will not be able to wrap it. As I understand the question.

Comment: This looks like the correct solution to me, thank you! My calling code to the retry function:

        `public override AttachmentUploadResult SyncUploadAttachment(string tableName, Guid rowGuid, byte?[] decompressedBytes, string fileName)
        {
            return UploadAttachmentToGLS(()=>
            {
                return AnotherService.SyncUploadAttachment(tableName, rowGuid, decompressedBytes, fileName);
            }`